# save sequence of images under specific names matlab

Tags: matlab

i have x images saved in a cell array calles IMG, and i already have cell array called NAM of size (1,x) contin names.
i wanna save the images under those names with the extention BMP.

```
for i=1:x
A=IMG{i}
N=NAM{i}
imwrite(A,'N.bmp'); %also imwrite(A,N.bmp);
end
```

***any ideas?***

Answer (score 0):

Well, you simply have to concatenate your strings `N` and `'.bmp'`:

```
for i = 1:x
    A = IMG{i}
    N = NAM{i}
    imwrite(A,[N '.bmp']);
end
```

or, in a more condensed syntax (without the for loop):

```
cellfun(@(x,y) imwrite(x, [y '.bmp']), IMG, NAM);
```

Best,